# Warnings suppressed with mclapply in R

Tags: r, warnings, mclapply

With `mclapply()` all issued warnings seems get suppressed:

```
library(multicore) 
mclapply(1:3, function(x) warning(x))
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "2"

[[3]]
[1] "3"
```

while `lapply` would give:

```
lapply(1:3, function(x) warning(x))
[[1]]
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "2"

[[3]]
[1] "3"

Warning messages:
1: In FUN(1:3[[3L]], ...) : 1
2: In FUN(1:3[[3L]], ...) : 2
3: In FUN(1:3[[3L]], ...) : 3
```

Any tips on how to avoid loosing the warnings?

Answer (score 5):

According to `mclapply`'s help page, in my opinion the argument `mc.silent` should allow you to chose if warnings are to be printed or not. Strangely, it does not do that. Setting it explictly to `TRUE` or `FALSE` does not have any effect in your situation.

So that leaves us only with a somewhat dirty hack: forcing R to print warnings as they occur.

```
options(warn=1)
mclapply(1:3, function(x) warning(x))

# Warning in FUN(1L[[1L]], ...) : 1
# Warning in FUN(2L[[1L]], ...) : 2
# Warning in FUN(3L[[1L]], ...) : 3
# [[1]]
# [1] "1"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "2"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "3"
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in GUI or RStudio. But the docs warn explicitly against using `mclapply` with these.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem too. If I'm reading the code correctly, `parallel::mclapply()` passes the `mc.silent` option to `parallel:mcparallel()`. But `mcparallel()` has this line:

```
sendMaster(try(eval(expr, env), silent = TRUE))
```

I think that's the place where the warnings would be sent back to the master process, but the `mc.silent` is not respected. That's my best guess about what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who will come around the same issue, here is a workaround:

```
safe_mclapply <- function(X, FUN, mc.cores, stop.on.error=T, ...){
  fun <- function(x){
    res_inner <- tryCatch({
      withCallingHandlers(
        expr = {
          FUN(x, ...)
        }, 
        warning = function(e) {
          message_parallel(trimws(paste0("WARNING [element ", x,"]: ", e)))
          # this line is required to continue FUN execution after the warning
          invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
        },
        error = function(e) {
          message_parallel(trimws(paste0("ERROR [element ", x,"]: ", e)))
        }
      )},
      error = function(e){
        # error is returned gracefully; other results of this core won't be affected
        return(e)
      }
    )
    return(res_inner)
  }
  
  res <- mclapply(X, fun, mc.cores=mc.cores)
  failed <- sapply(res, inherits, what = "error")
  if (any(failed == T)){
    error_indices <- paste0(which(failed == T), collapse=", ")
    error_traces <- paste0(lapply(res[which(failed == T)], function(x) x$message), collapse="\n\n")
    error_message <- sprintf("Elements with following indices failed with an error: %s. Error messages: \n\n%s", 
                             error_indices,
                             error_traces)
    if (stop.on.error)
      stop(error_message)
    else
      warning(error_message, "\n\n### Errors will be ignored ###")
  }
  return(res[!failed])
}

#' Function which prints a message using shell echo; useful for printing messages from inside mclapply when running in Rstudio
message_parallel <- function(...){
  system(sprintf('echo "\n%s\n"', paste0(..., collapse="")))
}
```

`safe_mclapply` above is a wrapper around `mclapply`. For each iteration it uses `withCallingHandlers` to catch and print warnings and errors; note that `invokeRestart("muffleWarning")` is required in order to continue `FUN` exection and return the result. Printing is done via `message_parallel` function which uses shell `echo` to print messages to R console (tested to work in Rstudio).

`safe_mclapply` provides few more features which you might find optional:

- along with the warning and error it prints character representation of `x` which I find useful because it gives an idea where the message comes from
- `tryCatch` around `withCallingHandlers` helps to return an error gracefully so that other results of the core are not affected
- after `mclapply` is executed, the indices of error results are printed
- `stop.on.error` provides an option to ignore any results which contain error and continue despite the errors

Side note: I personally prefer `pbmclapply` function from [pbmcapply](https://github.com/kvnkuang/pbmcapply) over `mclapply` which adds a progress bar. You can change `mclapply` to `pbmclapply` in the code above.

Small snippet to test the code:

```
X <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
f <- function(x){
  if (x == 3){
    warning("a warning")
    warning("second warning")
  }
  if (x == 6){
    stop("an error")
  }
  return(x + 1)
}

res <- safe_mclapply(X = X, FUN = f, mc.cores=16)
res_no_stop <- safe_mclapply(X = X, FUN = f, mc.cores=16, stop.on.error = F)
```